# Inputting Number in Array and Displaying it?

Tags: java, arrays, loops

How to make an array that is based on the users input? and then displaying it on descending order?
for example

Input:

```
Input Number of array = 3

Input no 1 = 2

Input no 2 = 4

Input no 3 = 7

Output: 7 , 4 , 2
```

Comment: Where is your tried code ?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a homework question, which does not include the required summary of the work done so far to solve the problem, nor a description of the difficulty encountered in solving it.

Comment: Remember that "[Questions asking for homework help must include a **summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem**, and a **description of the difficulty you are having solving it**.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are a beginner. So i will help you to get stand. Try this code.

```
class InputTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.print("Enter size of array: ");
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        int numberOfArray = scanner.nextInt();
        Integer[] input = new Integer[numberOfArray];

        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfArray; i++) {
            System.out.print("Input number " + (i + 1) + ": ");
            input[i] = scanner.nextInt();
        }

        Arrays.sort(input, Collections.reverseOrder());

        for (int i : input) {
            System.out.print(i + ",");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: He want's descending order.

Comment: thanks i didn't see that

Comment: Thank you..btw is there any other method instead of using the "Arrays.sort(input, Collections.reverseOrder());"

i tried this but didnt work, why?

'for (int i = numberOfArray; i > 0 ; i-- )
{
      System.out.print(input[i] + ",");
}'
Yes im beginner :)

Comment: You have to use one of sorting methods. Naturally java provides `Collections.sort(List)` and  `Collections.sort(List,Compartor)` methods. you cannot use `Collectios.sort(List)` since you need to sort reverse order. So you should use customized `Comparator` for reverse order. It's possible to use `Collections.reverseOrder()` `Comparator` other than creating new `Comparator`. This is the shortest way you can do that.

Comment: Ok Thanks man !! one more question please.. How do i put this in ascending order using Collections.sort(List)? i dont understand how to use comparator?

Comment: as i mentioned before just use `Collections.sort(List)` method